# HIVE - JSON Error FAILED: Add request failed : INSERT INTO `COLUMNS_V2` (`CD_ID`,`COMMENT`,`COLUMN_NAME`,`TYPE_NAME`,`INTEGER_IDX`) VALUES

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I am trying to define a HIVE EXTERNAL table using a Complex JSON with > 500 colyumns. I get an error when I hit a certain limit of columns and was wondering how to overcome it.

The full JSON has 548 columns for its structure. I can not upload the full JSON right now

The CREATE STATEMENT is successful until the line 243. IT flags the error below after I add the rest of the SCHEMA definition

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Add request failed : INSERT INTO `COLUMNS_V2` (`CD_ID`,`COMMENT`,`COLUMN_NAME`,`TYPE_NAME`,`INTEGER_IDX`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) 
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:451)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:732)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:752)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createTable(ObjectStore.java:855)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:98)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.createTable(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_core(HiveMetaStore.java:1394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStore.java:1427)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.create_table_with_environment_context(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$create_table_with_environment_context.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:8926)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$create_table_with_environment_context.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:8910)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor$1.run(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:106)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor.process(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:118)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'TYPE_NAME' at row 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Data too long for column 'TYPE_NAME'

The columns types are stored in the metastore within `columns_v2.type_name` which is defined as varchar(4000).
It is too small to hold one or more of your column type expression.

The number of columns is not an issue here.
The error is most likely caused by a `struct` containning a lot of fields.

e.g.
`mycol struct<col1:int,col2:string,...,col1000:date>`

In this case the column type is `struct<col1:int,col2:string,...,col1000:date>` and it is over 4000 characters.

As a work-around, see if you can avoid declaring some of the fields.

---

As for the OP comment
[JIRA

HiveHIVE-12274

Increase width of columns used for general configuration in the metastore.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12274)

Comment: @Markovitz, if I understand what you are saying, that the column TYPE_NAME checks he beginning of the nested data column and not for a single column only. Since I have a column defined an <array<struct>> this would be the start of the limit of 4000 character. With that being said, is there a way to increase the definition of columns_v2.type_name longer than varchar(4000)?? And where is this defined for HIVE??

Comment: (1) Check updated answer (2) Increasing the column size will most likely break few things along the way. Personally, I wouldn't date touching it.

Comment: @Markovitz, thanks for the clarification.. Does the definition count when you define cols with COMMENT like this  :`mycol struct<col1:int comment 'ID',col2:string,...,col1000:date>   I found this JIRA that talks about this issue and there seemed to be a fixed on 2.3.0 and 3.0.0 HiveHIVE-12274

Comment: Testing on Hive 2.1, It seems struct comments are stripped from the column type definition and not being saved anywhere...

Answer (score -2):

From given error it look like , length of column name is larger than allowed.

Maximum allowed column length is 4000 characters. Please check if any of the column is larger and changing such column name will resolve current issue.